# Trouble with catch-all routes in my node.js + react.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

To make refreshing or writting manually urls in my node.js + react.js app without "Cannot GET /*", I'm using this code on server-side to catch all routes and return index.html :

```
app.all('*',(req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'reactjs/dist/index.html'));
});
```

But app simply redirecting on '/'

Comment: The problem seem to be somewhere else.

Comment: @elmeister , if i using HashHistory it's okay, but ugly urls, that's why i use BrowserHistory

Comment: Show your ReactJS router code.

Comment: @elmeister                                                                                                 <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route component={MainContainer} history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path={"/"} component={Root} />
            <Route path={"myphotos"} onEnter={requireAuth(store)} component={MyPhotos} />
            <Route path={"users"} onEnter={requireAuth(store)} component={Users} />
          </Route >
        </Router>

Comment: Maybe it's better to update your question and share your `requireAuth` implementation - is there any redirect?

Comment: @elmeister, hah, there redirect to '/'. Is it opportunity to use manual url with my `requireAuth`

Comment: Would you be so kind to share github url to your project? Will check what's wrong.

Comment: @elmeister, I haven't github

Comment: bitbucket? zip your project and put somewhere?